# Is it neccessary for doctoral students to register car in a different EU country to their home country?

Tags: united-kingdom, france, insurance, driving, vehicle-registration

I'm about to start a Phd in France, moving from the UK, and am looking to get a car for when I am there. I would like to know if it is necessary to register a car bought in the UK, in France under these conditions. I have heard that students do not need to register cars, however, I will have a contract for my Phd, and will be living there all year round.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no special rules for students, but generally within Europe you can use a car abroad for a year (I think). If you are buying a car it might be better to buy it in France.

Comment: If you don't own a car yet, it's certainly better to buy one there, for it will be LHD.

Comment: Cheers for the advice. I was actually looking into buying a LHD here. It would mean I could drive over with my things, but also I've heard that it is a far better market for buying a car in the UK rather than in France (more people buy new in the UK, weak pound, typical milage lower in UK...)

Comment: I'll guess, however, that if you buy in France, you'll have less bureaucratic hassle compared to importing and re-registering a UK vehicle.

Comment: You can buy the car in UK, leave it registered to your parents' address, and just go back once a year (or not, nobody really cares). If you plan on using it later in UK, this makes sense.

Comment: @TomasBy, if you're going to answer please do so as an answer so that it can be downvoted as well as upvoted. Your claims are unreferenced and, except for the advice to buy in France, potentially expose OP to fines or worse.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: it's a grey area. You can live in France and own a UK car, parked in UK, that you happen to be not using.

Comment: @TomasBy - That's not the point.  The point is that you are answering in comments.  You should answer in answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be a resident of France, and as such you will have **one month** to re-register a car with foreign plates which you take with you.

http://www.frenchpropertylinks.com/essential/registering-car-france.html :

> Your UK driving licence is valid in France until it expires, while you are allowed to keep UK plates for up to six months if you are a non-resident of France, and up to one month for French residents. The time allowed for French residents can be extended up to a maximum of three months should a vehicle need to be approved via the DRIRE*. In the past these time limits have not seemed to have been strictly adhered to, but insurance laws are now tightening and this should no longer be the case.

* Direction Régionale de l'Industrie, de la Recherche et de l'Environnement

I think this official site is talking about the same one month limit (emphasis in original):

https://immatriculation.ants.gouv.fr/Vos-demarches/Immatriculer-un-vehicule-d-occasion-en-provenance-de-l-etranger/Immatriculer-un-vehicule-d-occasion-en-provenance-de-l-etranger

> Avant de faire circuler pour la 1ere fois votre véhicule d'occasion acquis à l'étranger (importé), vous devez **dans le délai d’un mois**, sous peine d’amende, faire établir le certificat d’immatriculation, aussi appelé « carte grise ».

*Disclaimer: note that I haven't lived in France and I don't know whether you will have some margin due to not being officially resident until some other bureaucratic process has finished. Hopefully someone with experience in the matter can give a better answer, but I was alarmed by some attempts to answer in the comments which I know to be wrong in Spain and which I fear could potentially open you up in the worst case to criminal charges by causing you to drive without valid insurance.*

Comment: Do you have a citation for "You're going to be a resident of France"?  Residency rules are usually different for undergraduates, and I would not be surprised if they were also different for post-grads.  (The English language site you link to is aimed at people buying a house in France and emigrating.)

Comment: @MartinBonner, residency rules are different for students in the sense that the documents they need to provide to justify their residence are different. They're still residents. https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/registering-residence/index_en.htm https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2651